# PHP replaces spaces with underscores

Tags: php

I have the problem, that PHP replaces all spaces with underscores in POST and GET variables.

For example if I have the URL: `http://localhost/proxy.php?user name=Max`
the browser will convert it to `http://localhost/proxy.php?user%20name=Max`.

But if I give the $_GET parameters out, the key is not `user name` but `user_name` (note the underscore)!

Is there any possibility to change this behaviour?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get PHP to stop replacing '.' characters in $\_GET or $\_POST arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651/get-php-to-stop-replacing-characters-in-get-or-post-arrays)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php):

> Dots in incoming variable names
>
> Typically, PHP does not alter the
>   names of variables when they are
>   passed into a script. However, it
>   should be noted that the dot (period,
>   full stop) is not a valid character in
>   a PHP variable name. For the reason,
>   look at it:
>
> ```
> <?php $varname.ext;  /* invalid variable name */ ?>
> ```
>
> Now, what
>   the parser sees is a variable named
>   $varname, followed by the string
>   concatenation operator, followed by
>   the barestring (i.e. unquoted string
>   which doesn't match any known key or
>   reserved words) 'ext'. Obviously, this
>   doesn't have the intended result.
>
> For this reason, it is important to
>   note that PHP will automatically
>   replace any dots in incoming variable
>   names with underscores.

And a comment on the page:

> The full list of field-name characters that PHP converts to _ (underscore) is the following (not just dot):
>
> ```
> chr(32) ( ) (space)
> chr(46) (.) (dot)
> chr(91) ([) (open square bracket)
> chr(128) - chr(159) (various)
> ```
>
> PHP irreversibly modifies field names containing these characters in an attempt to maintain compatibility with the deprecated register_globals feature.

Comment: Weirdly, the editor goes into an infinite loop if I try to make the second paragraph a quote instead of code

Comment: As far as I remember square brackets are not simply substituted by underscore, but rather allow multiple values to be put into an array.

Comment: I think it means if you have a single one, for example "hell[o".  If you have a matched pair then you're correct, it will create an array.

Comment: I don't buy their argument. Correct way to do it would be to keep $_GET intact and just modify those global variable names instead.

Answer (score 5):

I think the only possibility to get the wanted parameters, is to parse them on your own using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`:

```
$a_pairs = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
foreach($a_pairs AS $s_pair){
  $a_pair = explode('=', $s_pair);
  if(count($a_pair) == 1) $a_pair[1] = '';

  $a_pair[0] = urldecode($a_pair[0]);
  $a_pair[1] = urldecode($a_pair[1]);

  $GLOBALS['_GET'][$a_pair[0]] = $a_pair[1];
  $_GET[$a_pair[0]] = $a_pair[1];
}
```

Comment: noticed today, that "array" parameters such like "foo[0]=bar" wouldn't be interpreted as expected.

Comment: correct, but you probably don't want that anyway, if you are expected field names that are not correct PHP variable names and will be mangled by PHP built in parsing.

Comment: For a more concise (and less side-effecty) version of Rudi's query string parser, I've wrote this: `$query=array_reduce(array_map(function($part){return array_map(function($kv){return urldecode($kv); },explode('=',$part,2));},explode('&',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])),function($query,$pair){$query[$pair[0]]=@$pair[1];return $query;},[]);` (you might want to copy that out and format it properly)

Answer (score 3):

In the old crazy times of register_globals query string was unpacked by PHP into global variables, but the format of variable identifiers is constrained, so obviously spaces couldn't work. This limitation remained, and honestly I believe it's a good idea to keep it this way.

If you really cannot change spaces into underscores in your URLs, just mangle the $_GET array when you process the request and substitute every underscore by a space.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can remember, i've never seen spaces in URL parameter names...

I think, it would be better to convert all spaces of parameter names into "_".

Comment: I have the same problem with converting dots into "_". I wanted to use dots for direct matching with database table with alias table names, eg table_name.column_name. As php converts dots into "_" the string becomes un-usable "table_name_column_name". How would you solve it?