# Why does PHP replaces . with an underscore if it's a key in $_GET?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP replaces spaces with underlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283751/php-replaces-spaces-with-underlines)

Example: test.php?foo.bar=1

```
print_r($_GET);

// Array ( [foo_bar] => 1 )
```

Comment: you could always pass the name as the value?  test.php?1=foo.bar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a quote from [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#language.variables.external.dot-in-names)

> **Dots in incoming variable names**
>
> Typically, PHP does not alter the names of variables when they are
> passed into a script. However, it should be noted that the dot
> (period, full stop) is not a valid character in a PHP variable name.
> For the reason, look at it:
>
> ```
> <?php $varname.ext;  /* invalid variable name */ ?> Now, what the
> ```
>
> parser sees is a variable named $varname, followed by the string
> concatenation operator, followed by the barestring (i.e. unquoted
> string which doesn't match any known key or reserved words) 'ext'.
> Obviously, this doesn't have the intended result. For this reason, it
> is important to note that PHP will automatically replace any dots in
> incoming variable names with underscores.

Answer (score 2):

if the register_globals directive is set, array keys in $_GET must be used as variable names and dots, spaces as well as a variety of other characters aren't allowed in php variable names. In fear that you have that directive set, php replaces those 'invalid' characters

Answer (score 1):

Info from PHP Manual that accurate according to the question:

> > **Note:**
> >     Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For example  becomes $_REQUEST["a_b"].

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php