# Why isn't php explode extracting array values

Tags: php, arrays, query-string, explode, array-key

I have some date values (each with a trailing `=` sign) stored as a `&`-delimited string.

My `$_POST['dates']` string looks like this:

```
23.08.18=&22.08.18=&21.08.18=
```

I'm trying the following PHP code to extract the dates before inserting them into my database table. The code is currently not working.

```
foreach(explode('&', $_POST['dates']) as $value)  
{
    $value1 = explode('=', $value);
    foreach ($value1 as $x) {
    }
}
```

How can I isolate the date values?

Comment: Clarification: The problem is that the variables $value1 and $x are empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explode that doesn't return empty strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64570/explode-that-doesnt-return-empty-strings)

Comment: What is your exact expected result?  How might your input data vary?  Might you have duplicate dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$data = '23.08.18=&22.08.18=&21.08.18=';

//$delimiters has to be array
//$string has to be array

function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

 $ary = explode($delimiters[0],$string);
 array_shift($delimiters);
 if($delimiters != NULL) {
    foreach($ary as $key => $val) {
        $ary[$key] = multiexplode($delimiters, $val);
    }
 }
 return  $ary;
}

$exploded = multiexplode(array("=","&"),$data);

var_dump($exploded);
```

The result should be:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '23.08.18' (length=8)
  2 => string '22.08.18' (length=8)
  4 => string '21.08.18' (length=8)
```

We need to use `array_filter`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

**[EDIT]** mickmackusa's answer is the right tool for parse url parameters into variables.

Comment: Your proposal solved my problem, great stuff! After running the multiexplode function I just added a foreach loop to extract the content of the array.

Comment: @objelland don't multi-explode anything.  This answer is an inefficient hack that can be completely replaced with two native function calls.

Answer (score 3):

The function that you might be looking for is `parse_str()`.  You have a valid query string ([well, kind of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11084175/2943403)) with keys but no values, so you merely need to parse it and isolate the keys(dates). Unfortunately, the parser converts your dots to underscores.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uYhm5))

```
$string = '23.08.18=&22.08.18=&21.08.18=';
parse_str($string, $out);
var_export(array_keys($out));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '23_08_18',
  1 => '22_08_18',
  2 => '21_08_18',
)
```

And of course, you can repair the modified date values with `str_replace()`. [See this demo](https://3v4l.org/DIugX).

---

Or if you want to disregard `parse_str()`, you can use just one regex call that divides the string on `=` followed by an optional `&`:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OMLkQ))

```
$string = '23.08.18=&22.08.18=&21.08.18=';
var_export(preg_split('~=&?~', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '23.08.18',
  1 => '22.08.18',
  2 => '21.08.18',
)
```

---

Or without regex, just trim the last `=` and explode on `=&`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CCJDt))

```
$string = '23.08.18=&22.08.18=&21.08.18=';
var_export(explode('=&', rtrim($string, '=')));
// same output as preg_split()
```

Comment: @objelland I would appreciate if you would re-compare the answers on this page.