# How to configure Yii2 to accept only application/json & application/xml requests? (revoking/disallowing form-data)

Tags: php, yii2, content-type

I've set up my application's content negotiator for json and XML requests but this does not prevent sending in form-data which in some cases breaks the keys because dots and spaces are being converted to underscores see: [Why . (dot) and space are changed to _ (underscores) in PHP $_GET array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084175/why-dot-and-space-are-changed-to-underscores-in-php-get-array)

Both setting the content negotiator and the parser does not prevent this and the docs did not mention any "revokable" content types.

```
'bootstrap' => [
    'log', [
        'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
        'formats' => [
            'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            'application/xml' => Response::FORMAT_XML,
        ],
    ],
]
'components' => [
    'request' => [
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ],
        ],
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter ConentNegotiator used to negotiate response format based on request.

You need to create your own request filter. As an example you can use [VerbFilter](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-verbfilter).

The most common sample could be

```
class ContentTypeFilter extends Behavior
{
    public $contentTypes = [];

    // other code here ...

    public function beforeAction($event)
    {
        if (!$this->contentTypes) {
            return $event->isValid;
        }

        $contentType = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getContentType();
        if (!in_array($contentType, $this->contentTypes)) {
             $event->isValid = false;
             throw new \yii\web\UnsupportedMediaTypeHttpException('Method Not Allowed. This URL can only handle the following request content types: ' . implode(', ', $this->contentTypes) . '.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably use `yii\web\UnsupportedMediaTypeHttpException` instead of `yii\web\MethodNotAllowedHttpException` when the request uses unsupported format. [https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13)

Comment: is there any backlash in restricting the content types to json and XML?

Comment: @Theo no. But if this is ur api replace with underscore or use array like `data[var.name]`.

Comment: @SiZE sorry I don't fully understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Theo just don't use dots)