# Get raw post data

Tags: php, request

According to php manual nor php://input neither `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` work with `multipart/form-data` POST-requests.

"php://input allows you to read raw POST data. It is a less memory intensive alternative to `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` and does not need any special php.ini directives. php://input is not available with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`."

How can I get raw data for `multipart/form-data` forms?

Comment: If it is for the sake of counting bytes, can't you combine the count of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA bytes with the byte count of any $_FILES ?

Comment: @karim79, Because it isn't.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Direct answer: you can not do that. PHP insists on parsing it itself, whenever it sees the multipart/form-data Content-Type. The raw data will not be available to you. Sadly. But you can hack around it.

I hit a similar problem, a partner was sending incorrectly formatted data as multipart/form-data, PHP could not parse it and was not giving it out so I could parse it myself.

The solution? I added this to my apache conf:

```
<Location "/backend/XXX.php">
    SetEnvIf Content-Type ^(multipart/form-data)(.*) NEW_CONTENT_TYPE=multipart/form-data-alternate$2 OLD_CONTENT_TYPE=$1$2
    RequestHeader set Content-Type %{NEW_CONTENT_TYPE}e env=NEW_CONTENT_TYPE
</Location>
```

This will change the Content-Type of incoming request to XXX.php from multipart/form-data to multipart/form-data-alternate, which is enough to block PHP from trying to parse it

After this you can finally read the whole raw data from php://input and parse it yourself.

It is ugly, but I have not found a better or in fact any other solution - short of asking the partner to fix their side.

NB! When you do what I described here, $_FILES will be empty.

Comment: If I replace the Content-type header this way, i get back the php source in my browser.
It seems that the php engine will not process this request.

What is the trick?

I used different header replacements, none of them worked.

Comment: Seems like it's **possible** to do this with [`enable_post_data_reading`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19710850/632951).

Comment: @Pacerier - possible, my answer was written before php 5.4

Answer (score 12):

You can set [`enable_post_data_reading = Off`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading) and PHP won't intercept `multipart/form-data` data.

Requires: **PHP 5.4**

Comment: Interesting. Especially when the PHP Manual elsewhere insists it is impossible to get raw body in case of `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: @Anshul, Does the manual still state that? There's no coherent version of the manual. Some pages are version X while others are at version Z.

Comment: @Pacerier, I still believe its not possible to get the raw multipart/form-data. All of the following links suggest that:
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading
http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

Comment: @Anshul, `enable_post_data_reading = Off` gives you the raw multipart/form-data doesn't it?

Comment: @Pacerier, you were right. I was able to read post data of any kind with php://input when enable_post_data_reading was set to off. Tested with Apache as well as PHP's inbuilt web server.

The documentation needs to be updated for this. Unfortunately my previous attempts to get small changes in there went futile. :(

Comment: @Anshul, Which "previous attempts" are you talking about? Do you have a link?

Comment: @Pacerier, not related to this but here it goes. I submitted a user note http://news.php.net/php.notes/183258 for page http://php.net/manual/en/gearman.examples-reverse-task.php. There was too much friction to get the stuff in and eventually I left it. Moreover, for another bug report, it ended up with status not a bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49322 finally I found my peace in making best of the PHP I know of :)

Answer (score 5):

I didn't implement this fully, but it looks like it should work.  In `Apache conf`:

```
SetEnvIf Content-Type ^(multipart/form-data)(.*) MULTIPART_CTYPE=$1$2
RequestHeader set Content-Type application/x-httpd-php env=MULTIPART_CTYPE
RequestHeader set X-Real-Content-Type %{MULTIPART_CTYPE}e env=MULTIPART_CTYPE
```

Setting the `Content-Type` to `application/x-httpd-php` appears to solve the original problem of PHP parsing the body, and the problem **Norbert Farkas** reported: *"Apache sends back PHP source code"*.  The body is then available on `php://input`, and the real content type in the `X-Real-Content-Type` header.  (That header may not be necessary for you -- the `MULTIPART_CTYPE` variable didn't seem to be showing up in my `$_ENV`, but the new header did.)  All other requests should be handled as usual.

Thanks to **Anti Veeranna** for most of it! :)

EDIT: P.S. Obviously it's Apache-specific, but in some of the other configurations of PHP there may very well be easier ways.

Answer (score -2):

```
//Get the raw POST data
$postBody = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Comment: *php://input is not available with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`*