# How to enable and use HTTP PUT and DELETE with Apache2 and PHP?

Tags: php, apache, rest

It should be so simple. I've followed every tutorial and forum I could find, yet I can't get it to work. I simply want to build a RESTful API in PHP on Apache2.

In my VirtualHost directive I say:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    <Limit GET HEAD POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Limit>
</Directory>
```

Yet every PUT request I make to the server, I get 405 method not supported.

Someone advocated using the Script directive, but since I use mod_php, as opposed to CGI, I don't see why that would work.

People mention using WebDAV, but to me that seems like overkill. After all, I don't need DAV locking, a DAV filesystem, etc. All I want to do is pass the request on to a PHP script and handle everything myself. I only want to enable PUT and DELETE for the clean semantics.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to configure anything. Just make sure that the requests map to your PHP file and use requests with path info. For example, if you have in the root a file named `handler.php` with this content:

```
<?php

var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
var_dump($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);

if (($stream = fopen('php://input', "r")) !== FALSE)
    var_dump(stream_get_contents($stream));
```

The following HTTP request would work:

```
Established connection with 127.0.0.1 on port 81
PUT /handler.php/bla/foo HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:81
Content-length: 5
 
boo
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 29 May 2010 16:00:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.13 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.0
Content-Length: 89
Content-Type: text/html
 
string(3) "PUT"
string(20) "/handler.php/bla/foo"
string(8) "/bla/foo"
string(5) "boo
"
Connection closed remotely.
```

You can hide the "php" extension with [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html) or you can make URLs completely logical with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

See also the documentation for the [AcceptPathInfo](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) directive and this question on how to [make PHP not parse POST data when enctype is `multipart/form-data`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361673).

Comment: Using cURL command line: "curl -X PUT --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" --data-binary "@1.gif" -v /handler.php/bla/foo"   and inside PHP file dump contents into file. It works great.
However, I need to send some extra information eg. token with the request to upload file. I think I should use POST.

Comment: The token can be in the header too ;)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. @AndreasJansson, what did you change to get it working? I have the same problem, and saying "you don't need to do anything, it already works" is NOT HELPFUL.

Comment: I have the same problem. 405 error occur before it reach .php page. So I cannot map anything.

Comment: _"Just make sure that the requests map to your PHP file"_ Right... but **how**? Agreed, not a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reason was that I accidentally made requests to a **non existent path** (`/users`).

Curiously, `curl -v --request PUT localhost:8080/users` returns `405 Method Not Allowed` instead of the `404 Not Found` I expected, whereas `curl -v --request GET localhost:8080/users` returns `404 Not Found`.

`curl -v --request PUT localhost:8080/` and `curl -v --request DELETE localhost:8080/` return `200 OK` as expected and reach the index.php in my DocumentRoot using nothing but the default php:apache docker image.

Answer (score -2):

AllowOverride AuthConfig

try this. Authentication may be the problem. I was working with a CGI script written in C++, and faced some authentication issues when passed DELETE. The above solution helped me. It may help in your case too.

---

Also even if you don't get the solution for your problem of PUT and DELETE, do not stop working rather use "CORS". It is a google chrome app, which will help you bypass the problem, but remember it is a temporary solution, so that your work or experiments doesn't remain freeze for long. Obviously, you cannot ask your client to have "CORS" enabled to run your solution, as it may compromise systems security.

Comment: Why do you think that authentication may be the root cause, despite the fact that the stated problem is a 405, not a 403? What has CORS got to do with either HTTP method acceptability, or authentication? Could you please clarify your answer, to make it clear which of these three concepts you're talking about?

Answer (score -3):

On linux, `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf dans php5.load`  exists. If not, enables this modules (may require to `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`).

Comment: Can you please use the code tags? That makes it a lot more readable.

Answer (score -4):

IIRC the purpose of the form method attribute was to define different transport methods. Consequently, HTML 5.2 only defines GET, POST, and DIALOG methods for transport and dialog action, not how the server should process the data.

Ruby-on-rails solves this problem by using POST/GET for everything and adding a hidden form variable that defines the actual ReST method. This approach is more clumsy and error-prone, but does remove the burden from both the HTML standard and browser developers.

The form method was defined before ReST, so you cannot define ReST in HTML, even after enabling Apache and PHP because the browsers conform to HTML and therefore default to GET/POST for all non-HTML defined values. That means, when you send a form to the browser with a PUT method, the browser changes that to GET and uses that instead. The hidden variable, however, passes through everything unchanged, so you can use that to customise your form handling process.

Hope that helps

Comment: Are you sure you meant "HTML"?

Comment: Yes, because the http method name is required in the html form tag. The problem is browser developers never implemented a flexible method, probably because it seemed impossible to know what data structure (transport) should be used for an arbitrary method. This is why ruby on rails uses a hidden variable instead. The answer given is actually ridiculous, because it replaces the browser with php code. Really?

Comment: Well, [no, it isn't](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-method).

Comment: Yes, it is. From HTML 5.3: 4.10.1.3. Configuring a form to communicate with a server

This section is non-normative.

Form submissions are exposed to servers in a variety of ways, most commonly as HTTP GET or POST requests. To specify the exact method used, the method attribute is specified on the form element. This doesn’t specify how the form data is encoded, though; to specify that, you use the enctype attribute. You also have to specify the URL of the service that will handle the submitted data, using the action attribute.

Comment: Click on the link I gave you. Method can be omitted. Its default is `GET`.

Comment: Doesn't matter, anyway; this question is about the HTTP server returning an error code, not about HTML or Ruby-on-Rails or REST or whatever else you're talking about. The OP didn't even mention `<form>`.

Comment: The error code is because the PUT and DELETE don't work as the POST and GET do. They should. The OP didn't specify a mechanism, only how to enable it in apache. My answer is technically correct. What you proposed is a work-a-round. If the OP wasn't using html to POST and GET then he would know how to do PUT and DELETE in http, but he doesn't, so he isn't using http to POST and GET, which brings us to form and method. I read your link and it didn't show PUT and DELETE. It should according to the standard.

Comment: That's your opinion which is not acceptable here. In fact there is no standard solution. https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=10671

Comment: It's not my opinion. I literally linked to the standard document lol

Answer (score -8):

The technical limitations with using PUT and DELETE requests does not lie with PHP or Apache2; it is instead on the burden of the browser to sent those types of requests.

Simply putting <form action="" method="PUT"> will not work because there are no browsers that support that method (and they would simply default to GET, treating PUT the same as it would treat gibberish like FDSFGS). Sadly those HTTP verbs are limited to the realm of non-desktop application browsers (ie: web service consumers).

Comment: He said he wants a restful API so it may well have nothing to do browsers. Anyway, current browsers support PUT, DELETE etc. through the XmlHttpRequest