# PUT request modrewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have file /tm/index.php which I want to rewrite with such rule:

```
RewriteRule ^tm/([a-zA-Z1-9]*)$ /tm/index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

When I try to send PUT request to rewrited url I get HTTP error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /tm/295014.</p>
</body></html>
```

I can't find out what to do. When I call /tm/index.php?p=295014 it works fine, but I can't use it in such way. Please help to change rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with your rewrite rule, your `index.php` isn't setup to accept the `PUT` method. That's what the 405 error is telling you.

Take a look at this answer for allowing the PUT request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2935714/851273