# Zend 1.12 Rest PUT method not allowed

Tags: zend-framework, zend-rest

Since I migrated to AWS and update to PHP 5.4 and Zend 1.12, I have a problem with the PUT & DELETE methods.

A quick exemple :

/** Zend 1.12 **/

/** bootstrap / routes **/

```
$front = \Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->setParam('bootstrap',$this);
//REST API
$router = $front->getRouter();
$restRoute = new Zend_Rest_Route($front, array(), array(
    'default' => array('rest'),
));
$router->addRoute('rest', $restRoute);
```

/** restController **/

```
//module : default 

class RestController extends  \Zend_Rest_Controller
public function init(){
    parent::init();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
}
public function headAction(){}

public function indexAction()
{
    Throw new AppException(Translator::translate('index not yet implemented...'));
}
public function getAction()
{
    die('get');
}
public function putAction(){
 die('put');
}
```

/*** TestCase ***/

```
curl -X GET http://XXXX/rest/MS4xMjU2LjEyNTguMTI2MS4tbW9kZWxzXGNvcmVcbW9kZWxcZXhlcmNpc2VcZXhlcmNpc2VfcXVlc3Rpb24tMTQy
```

Result : get ===> OK

```
curl -X PUT http://XXXX/rest/MS4xMjU2LjEyNTguMTI2MS4tbW9kZWxzXGNvcmVcbW9kZWxcZXhlcmNpc2VcZXhlcmNpc2VfcXVlc3Rpb24tMTQy
```

Result :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /index.php.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at XXXXX Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

===> Not OK

I don't have to use WebDav (or other) Apache plugin to enable PUT/DELETE request. The PHP Handler deals with that, not Apache. 
So why, the GET is OK, and the PUT not? Why Apache says something about index.php instead of /rest/RestController.php?

I saw that Zend update its Zend_Rest_Controller since 1.12. Now, I've to declare the "headAction" function, but I didn't find documentation on this point...

If you have any idea...

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable and use HTTP PUT and DELETE with Apache2 and PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934554/how-to-enable-and-use-http-put-and-delete-with-apache2-and-php)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is rooted in Apache configuration.
Maybe you should go ahead and add something like

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    <Limit GET HEAD POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Limit>
</Directory>
```

to your apache configuration.

Check out this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/148865/enable-put-method-on-apache-for-any-php-script).

Comment: I already tried this solution, but it didn't work neither. And on my previous configuration, I didn't need to change the Apache configuration.

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
               <Limit HEAD GET POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
               </Limit>
    </Directory>

Comment: The problem is not in ZF anyway. In my environment your snippet works just fine.