# Working with HLS and Push content to Apache

Tags: apache, http, streaming, push, live

I have customer that have a envivio encoder. Today they push live HLS streams to Akamai.
Now the they want to try to push the stream to us. Buw wat kind of webserver do I need and how do I config the server to save the push stream to webb-storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your encoder (as well as many others) is using HTTP PUT to publish the video. Apache web server can do the trick easily. 
if you need help enabling the HTTP PUT functionality in Apach -, try
[How to enable and use HTTP PUT and DELETE with Apache2 and PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934554/how-to-enable-and-use-http-put-and-delete-with-apache2-and-php)