# Apache put : The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, put, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to allow "put" method on my apache 2.2, but what ever i tried (Limit, LimitExcept ...),
i always got the following error :

```
405 Method Not Allowed
The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL
```

This is my http.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com:80    
    DocumentRoot "D:/test"
    Include "D:/conf/httpd.conf"
    <Directory />
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        <LimitExcept GET PUT POST DELETE>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </LimitExcept>
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

**UPDATE :**
I readed some related posts like the following :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934554/how-to-enable-and-use-http-put-and-delete-with-apache2-and-php
```

but i don't have any script php or cgi.
I just want to redirect http call (get, post, put delete ...) to mock files with mod_rewrite like that :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/maincall/customer
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} PUT
RewriteRule /maincall/customer %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mockfolders/PUT/data.json
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem when doing server-testing use postman. Actually this problem occur because you typing an error URL. Try fixing the URL that you hit. And it works for my problem

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :

- install perl to create cgi script
- define the following rules in the httpd.conf :

  AddHandler cgi-script .pl
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my/url
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} PUT
   RewriteRule /my/url "C:/Apache/Apache2.2/cgi-bin/myurlput.pl"

and it's worked

Comment: Does this mean that there is not way for Apache to handle a PUT file request without an additional script ?