# How to use get request in page template (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, get, wordpress-theming

How can I use the `get` method in WordPress?
I'm using a page template and I want to `get`.

When I use the `get` method in wordpress it redirects me to the URL without the `?page=1`.

Please note that post method is working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `get` in wordpress. It sounds like you might have a server misconfig. Checkout this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484888/enable-put-and-delete-methods-on-apache-2-4) for information on how to make sure apache is configured correctly.