# How to get raw request in PHP?

Tags: php, post, httprequest

I have a script called api.php on my server. I call it from other server using POST request. Is there any way to get in my api.php raw contents of POST request?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361673/get-raw-post-data for POST multipart data.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "raw"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use the following code

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: returns an empty string on xampp with apache with php 5.5 :/

Answer (score -2):

I think using the error control operator (@) would be better as who will request the API may not send a body in his request.

Also, take the data in raw as a payload variable and then parse it to an associative array to access data in a simple way.

```php
$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
// parse payload data to an associative array 
//(second argument specifies if it should be an associative array or not)
$data = json_decode($payload, true);
```