# Reliable way to get the raw HTTP request body in PHP

Tags: php, apache, http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get raw post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361673/get-raw-post-data)

Reading from `php://input` works, except when the request body is in `multipart/form-data` format, in which case nothing is read.

I've heard that `php://input` can only be read from once, which is what I suspect may be causing this (i.e. PHP may be reading from `php://input` when it sees `multipart/form-data` before I can get my hands on it). However, in testing I've found that I am able to read from the stream multiple times without issue.

Is there a way to get the request body no matter what format?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
$body = '';   

$handle = fopen('php://input', 'r');
while(!feof($handle)) {
    $body .= fread($handle, 1024);
}
```

Comment: You're right, thanks. Shame it requires such an ugly hack.

Comment: If you are using PHP 5.4, you can try http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading But then you have to make custom parsers for populating `$_POST` and `$_FILES`

Answer (score 0):

You can make PHP always populate $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA 
See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data
not the most efficient way of doing it though.

Comment: It says right there *$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".*

Comment: $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is now deprecated.  Please us 'php://input'

Comment: The issue with using `php://input` is if one part of the script (a lib include, or sdk) already reads `php://input`, then any time later in a script execution that tries to do the same thing, fails. This is the most stupid depreciation of something useful, ever done to later php versions.