# Reading non key/value POST data from PHP

Tags: php, apache, http, post

I have a system that POSTs data to an URL without sending key/value pairs but instead using an XML payload. I need to read that XML data using PHP under Apache, but PHP's `$_POST` array is for key/value pairs and thus is blank as no keys are provided.

I tried reading from `php://input` and `php://stdin`, but that's also blank.

How can I read the raw POST data using PHP? I cannot control the input as it is being generated by a third-party application. Imagine this being a RESTful URL that accepts XML payload.

Comment: how you sending xml data?

Comment: @RakeshSharma it is being sent by a third-party application. Imagine POSTing with CURL:$data = '<xml><data>foo</data></xml>'; curl_setopt_array($ch, array(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data, CURLOPT_POST => TRUE));

Comment: Can you confirm that the data that the third party is supposed to send is actually being sent (i.e. are you sure you're actually receiving the data at all)?

Comment: I am certain that it is sending the data.

Comment: Which of the two options solved the problem for you?

Comment: I changed Apache config as I need to handle multipart/form-data as is for other scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the PHP manual, `php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".`.  If this is what's being POSTed to you, PHP will not allow you to access the raw data.
One workaround to this issue: 
(*source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361673/get-raw-post-data*)

Add this to your apache.conf:

```
<Location "/backend/XXX.php">
        SetEnvIf Content-Type ^(multipart/form-data)(.*) MULTIPART_CTYPE=$1$2
        RequestHeader set Content-Type application/x-httpd-php env=MULTIPART_CTYPE
        RequestHeader set X-Real-Content-Type %{MULTIPART_CTYPE}e env=MULTIPART_CTYPE
</Location>
```

As of PHP 5.4, there is also the "enable-post-data-reading" ini setting (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading).

From the PHP manual: *"Disabling this option causes $_POST and $_FILES not to be populated. The only way to read postdata will then be through the php://input stream wrapper. This can be useful to proxy requests or to process the POST data in a memory efficient fashion."*

Try disabling this setting and then reading from `php://input`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check and see if there is any information stored in your post by doing:

```
print_r( $_POST );
```

What you would like to do might be sending the XML data in a key named `xml` or something like that resulting in `$_POST['xml'] = 'your xml code'`

**EDIT:**

It would also be nice if you could post the code you use to create the `$_POST`.

Comment: POST is sent by a third-party application that I cannot control, so I cannot send a key/value pair. Imagine this as being a RESTful URL with an XML payload.

Comment: Are you getting any result from print_r( $_POST ) or print_r( $_GET ) containing your data?

Comment: They are blank arrays.