# .htacces-SetEnvIf To NGinx-fastcgi_param about RequestHeader SetEnvIf

Tags: php, apache, nginx, url-rewriting

apache .htacces like this 
how .htaccess file to Nginx

```
Content-Type ^(multipart/form-data)(.*) MULTIPART_CTYPE=$1$2 
RequestHeader set Content-Type application/x-httpd-php env=MULTIPART_CTYPE 
RequestHeader set X-Real-Content-Type %{MULTIPART_CTYPE}e env=MULTIPART_CTYPE
```

Comment: Can you explain in human language what does this code do?

Comment: yes, the question like this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361673/get-raw-post-data

Comment: Get raw post data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361673/get-raw-post-data

Comment: So it just change `Content-Type` header for PHP?

Comment: yes  with apache that  get raw input  .