# Accessing Raw POST via php://input for forms with Content Type multipart/form-data not working

Tags: php, http

We have a proxy PHP script and access POST form data via

```
$postPayload = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

which usually works.

(The reason to not use `$_POST` is that we sometimes have duplicate form input names which PHP suppresses)

Now we have a form with

```
<form name="form" method="post" 
   action="/script.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

In this case `file_get_contents('php://input');` returns an empty string.

It can be reproduced with

```
curl 'http://localhost/script.php' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Referer: http://localhost/script.php?commandCode=NO_AUTH_REGIST_OPEN_USER&amp;lang=de' -H 'Origin: http://misumi-europe.com.orange.imi.local' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryk3IVneARm3kqJ0fs' --data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundaryk3IVneARm3kqJ0fs\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="commandCode"\r\n\r\nNO_AUTH_NEXT\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryk3IVneARm3kqJ0fs\r\n' --compressed
```

How can I access the RAW POST data in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get raw post data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361673/get-raw-post-data)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`multipart/form-data` is not send to php://input, only to $_POST.

In php.ini you can set `enable-post-data-reading=off` to change this but $_POST will *always* be empty. See http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading

You might set it for single pages using .htaccess

```
php_value  enable-post-data-reading off
```

There is also an apache hack:

```
<Location "/backend/XXX.php">
    SetEnvIf Content-Type ^(multipart/form-data)(.*) NEW_CONTENT_TYPE=multipart/form-data-alternate$2 OLD_CONTENT_TYPE=$1$2
    RequestHeader set Content-Type %{NEW_CONTENT_TYPE}e env=NEW_CONTENT_TYPE
</Location>
```

See also: [Get raw post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361673/get-raw-post-data)

Comment: I am sorry, I had already written half of the answer when I found the duplicate so I added the link. I also vote for close...

Comment: No, I wrote the first part. Found the apache hack, added a link and copied the important part [as everybody is supposed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) to. I did not delete my answer because it does summe up everything I found and also adds the .htaccess because the OP complained about not being able to change those settings on the server. But anyway feel free to down vote.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix it like this in `.htaccess`

```
<Files "script.php">
# make post data always available in the proxy
php_flag enable_post_data_reading 0
</Files>
```