# Input checkbox name converts period signs into underlines on post

Tags: php, forms

I am working on an image gallery at the moment. When a user is logged in, an x appears over each image and a checkbox next to it to enable the user to delete that image. Only if the checkbox is checked will the image be deleted.

They are both in a (one for each image in the gallery), the small image "x.gif" is an input type="image" that submits the $_POST form. The checkbox inherits the name of the image and is to prevent accidentally pressing the x button and deleting an image.

The problem is that the checkbox name, upon posting it gets converted from (for instance)

"Image.jpg" to "Image_jpg"

When i test it with print_r($_POST);

Should I create code for replacing _jpg or _gif into .jpg and .gif after the post or is there a way to make it possible to use period signs in input names?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend changing the structure of your form to have a field for confirmation (the checkbox) one field for the name (hidden) and your submission button (image):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="confirmation" />
<input type="hidden" name="target" value="file.jpg" />
<input type="image" />
```

Comment: The hidden field is a great idea. I feel kinda bad for not thinking of that myself. Think I'll use that.

Thanks a lot for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

This is standard PHP behaviour. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651/can-i-get-php-to-stop-replacing-characters-in-get-or-post-arrays).

Doing a manual str_replace on `_jpg` or `_gif` is a bad idea because those strings could also appear within a file name:

`winter_impression_jpg_strong_colours.jpg`

In that case, the file name would become unusable.

You could alternatively either

- Mask the dots using some other combination of characters (e.g. `___DOT___`)
- Change the logic: Have numbered fields (`checkbox_1` `checkbox_2`....) and store the name in a separate field (`checkbox_1_name = "image.jpg"`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. 

It's true that a replace could change file names like that, so it would be better to do a replace just at the 4 last characters. However, as someone suggested, a hidden field would do the trick and work well with the code i have so far since values can have dots in them.

Comment: @Rakoon yup, a hidden field will do fine. (That's what I meant by changing the logic.)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `input type="image"` use the normal `img` tag and place the `x` image in that and then modify your code as per those changes otherwise you can simply replace the underscore with a dot.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Decided to go for a solution with hidden inputs.