# getting error when i send the textfield value through ajax request to php using sencha touch

Tags: php, sencha-touch-2

my view contains the following code

```
this.keypadDisplay = Ext.create('Ext.field.Text', {
            xtype:'textfield',
            disabled: true,
            value: ''
        });
```

my ajax request code is

```
handler: function(b, e) {
                    var thisUser = this.getValue();
                   alert(thisUser);
                    //params[this.getSubmitParamName()] = this.getValue();
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url:'http://localhost/sencha2011/keypadapp/code.php',
                        params: thisUser,
                        method:'GET',
                        success: function(response, opts){
                            var text = response.responseText;
                            console.log(response.responseText);
                            alert(thisUser);
                            //alert(this.getValue());
                            //alert('Value: ' + this.getValue());
                            Ext.Msg.alert('success', text);
                        },
                        failure: function(response, opts){
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Error','Error while submitting the form');
                            console.log(response.responseText);
                           },
                        scope: this
                    });
            }
```

here i'm getting the "this.getValue" successfully. i want to insert to this.getValue to the code table.
my code.php contains the following code

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db('form',$con);

$insert = "INSERT INTO codetable(password) VALUES ('".$_GET['thisUser.value']."')";

if(mysql_query($insert))
{
    echo('values inserted successfully');
}
else
{
    echo('failure' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

here im getting the error as "Undefined index:thisUser.Value in  .../keypadapp/code.php " on line 5.
can anyone help me to ? thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign param value to variable in ajax call:

```
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url:'http://localhost/sencha2011/keypadapp/code.php',
                    params: 'thisuser='+thisUser,
```

Then in php, access the value:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO codetable(password) VALUES ('".$_GET['thisuser']."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$_GET['thisUser.value']` to `$_GET['thisUser_value']` dots in `$_GET` and `$_POST` get converted to underscores in PHP. See this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/68742/589909

**Update**

Looking closer at your code you can't get javascript values of an object in php like you are doing. I assume that `thisUser` is an object. So when passing it as a param its properties will be posted to the server individually. So if it had a property called `foo` you would get it like so. `$_GET['foo'];` also you could dump the get request to see what was sent. `var_dump($_GET);`