# how to receive the URL parameter with dot in php

Tags: php

How can i dynamically received the parameter with dot in php.

Say i know there is a URL parameter `"hl"` but the there is some dynamic values are appended with in the parameter name like

`"h1.u", "hl.p"` is it possible to these parameters with dynamic names?

Comment: You're talking about $_GET, right?

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Yes

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this is known behavior and there are some workarounds out there (creating a function to get the actual $_GET parameters).

Check out this question for more details: [Get PHP to stop replacing '.' characters in $_GET or $_POST arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651/get-php-to-stop-replacing-characters-in-get-or-post-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, dot characters aren't allowable in GET variables. GET replaces them with '_'. This is fine if your variables won't naturally have any underscores: in the beginning of your PHP script, you just look for any dynamic combination of 'h1_' plus the whole deck of possible letters (or, adapt Ronnie's answer to use '_' instead of '.').

I run into situations where _ is a valid character in GET variable names, but I need a way to specify '.' too. So I use Javascript to ensure that all '.' are turned into '__' (two underscores) beforehand, then I look for this pattern in the receiving PHP.

Comment: I saw someone downvoted this answer, any interest in clarifying why? Sorry if it wasn't helpful!

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` is an enumerated array.

That means, you can loop through the entire `$_GET` array and check for 'variants'.

Meaning the parameter h1.u would be located in `$_GET['h1.u'];`

Searching could work like this:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key, "h1") !== false) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

This code will iterate through the entire array and look for anything which contains 'h1' somewhere in it's key and do something with it.

`strpos` will return `boolean false` if it's not found, which is why you need to do a typecheck instead of checking for `not 0`, since h1 could well be located at position 0 (first character)

Comment: Refugnic, am I missing something? Far as I know, dots aren't allowable in GET variable names. When you run a php script with GET vars like ?h1.u=14&h1.p=7, it will be translated into $_GET['h1_u'] and $_GET['h1_p'].

Comment: @TopherHunt Would you mind reading the comment I posted in the reply with the 2 upvotes? I didn't know there was a problem with those variable names, but my answer was generic enough to remain standing. If you want to know if the key name has a particular chain of characters in it, you can do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$gets=array_keys($_GET);
foreach($item in $gets){
  $check1=explode($item, ".");
  if(count($check1) <2){
    //No appended keys recieved
  }

  else{
    $key = $check1[0];
    $apeendedPart= $check1[1];
  }

 //Do something with these two
}
```

Not tested, small bugs maybe present.. I'll correct it if you found one.