# URL redirect not working for contains question mark "?" in the url in magento

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I have some issue in URL redirecting.i created url redirect (in admin) without quotation it's working fine. like `http//www.domain.com/products/wingback-chair/leadimage.position=3`

when ever i created url redirect (in admin) with quotation mark like `http//www.domain.com/products/wingback-chair?leadimage.position=3` the URL redirect does not work.it's shows 404 error.

Please tell me if there any possibilities via htacces convert "?" to "/" or any idea/suggestion. i appreciate you.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the first url you gave works and you want to redirect it to the second ?

Comment: did you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

dot (.) is not the really good character to put in a url parameters and it is most probably that that makes things go wrong. you can probably use underscore (_) or some other thing. If you really need to use a dot, you should have a look to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16999694/2660794

Comment: Hi Christophe Ferreboeuf, Thanks for your reply.Actually i created url rewrite (via magento admin) for existing URL only i.e URL mapping.my problem is the url contain "?" question mark the URL rewrite does not work.