# db table names as alias in php GET-paramter?

Tags: php, html

I am looking for a possibility to pass db table name and column name via php and GET parameter.

I have a data grid with following structure:
table_name1.column1, table_name2.column1, table_name2.column1.

There is a search function for the grid, where I need those parameters.

From the url "`?table_name1.column1=22`" I am getting through the $_GET only `table_name1_column1=22`

How would you solve that?

Comment: are you sure that you want to include table and column names in a GET situation, instead of creating some mapped codes?

Comment: I was thinking about that, but it is actually a password secured application with very few users, that are not going to crack the application...

Comment: not really safe what you are doing, but u may want to urlencode your GET parameters

Answer (score 3):

Encode the variable with base64 and decode before you use.
I know that's dirty.

But php variables doesn't support periods (dots)

Comment: Simply you are asking about, why the variables passed with dots are converted to underscore.. rite?

Comment: Here is a reference too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651/get-php-to-stop-replacing-characters-in-get-or-post-arrays

Comment: No, I am not asking why, I am asking whether there is a workaround for this? I knew the link you posted here.

Comment: If you could use some other character for . And replacing it in every get variable. Base64encode works.

Comment: I use "!" instead of dot. Then before the use in the algorithm I am doing a str_replace. I am sure that this is not most egelante solution but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a documented feature of PHP. Its basically because PHP cannot have variable names with dots in them.

```
$x.y = 1  // is an invalid variable name
```

[MANUAL Convert dots to _ in GET & POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

Comment: but at the same time this works fine: $foo["table.column"]=10;
print_r($foo);

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialize function of php to pass the text "table_name1.column1" in url. But for that you need to do few coding to get the result. Below I have given code which you can use:

**Page1.php**

```
<?php
$test = serialize('table_name1.column1=11::table_name2.column2=22');
?>
<a href='Page2.php?qs=<?php echo $test?>'>test</a>
```

Use this $test to pass as query string. In above example, I am passing on anchor tag click.

**Page2.php**

use following code to Unserialize the query string and use the values.

```
<?php

$test2 = unserialize($_GET['qs']);

$ex = explode('::',$test2);

$new_arr = array();
foreach($ex as $val)
{
    $ex2 = explode('=',$val);
    $new_arr[$ex2[0]] = $ex2[1];
}

echo $new_arr['table_name1.column1']; //print 11
echo $new_arr['table_name2.column2']; //print 22


?>
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to seperate each parameter with `&`.

So: `?table=table_name1&column=column1`

Comment: but if I have 10 columns it makes the url really long and un-readable (as I have to pass here also other parameters like the mode of the grid etc). Furthermore I built an algorithm for matching GET-parameters with my SQL-query, where I have such columns like table.column....