# Encoded JQuery Url not decoding correctly in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am using .ajax() to send a request to the server. The server is using PHP to process the request.

According to [php urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php), $_REQUEST is already decoded and  Plus symbols ('+') are decoded to a space character.

What I have found is that Plus symbols are being decoded to a underscore ('_'). This is true for both + and %20. Is there any way around this? This seems like unexpected behavior.

Code sample for what its worth:

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
       url: 'mySite.php',
       method: 'POST',
       data: $(this).serialize()
    });
```

php:

```
$myVar = "Veh #";
if (isset($_REQUEST["$myVar"])){
//do stuff
}
//to see request
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

The var_dump gives

array(1) {["Veh_#"]=> string(1) "6"}

I would expect is to be

array(1) {["Veh #"]=> string(1) "6"}

fiddler data posted:

Veh+%23=6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be incorrect as I'm still learning PHP, but I think this is standard behaviour when using GET and POST in PHP.

see here in the documentation

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

I not aware of anyway around this.

also see this stack overflow question

[Get PHP to stop replacing '.' characters in $_GET or $_POST arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651/get-php-to-stop-replacing-characters-in-get-or-post-arrays)

Comment: Ah, the confusion was from me reading "Plus symbols ('+') are decoded to a space character." and not reading that "Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For example <input name="a.b" /> becomes $_REQUEST["a_b"]." Which is a bit annoying.

Comment: exactly, its a bit confusing on a first parse, but makes sense once you digest it.

Answer (score 0):

> Note:
>
> Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores.

([php.net - external variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php))