# wrong with $_Files key

Tags: php

I have a big problem, I have written code in mobile application to upload file to server, but the problem that I have set dot inside `$_Files['User.file'];`

When I invoke `$_Files['User.file']` to upload the file, then it's seem there is no such `$_Files['User.file']` and I think the problem because I have wrote dot inside the key, and the server cannot recognize the file as invalid key

I know that it's possible to change the dot from key but it's take more time in mobile application.

There is any way to deal with that problem? Such as upload files without knowing any keys?

Any suggestions?

This is my code, there is no files:

```
<?php
   $new_image_name = "YEAH.jpg";
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["User.file"]["tmp_name"], "/var/www/TEST/".$new_image_name);
?>
```

Comment: What does your upload form html look like?

Comment: Show us `var_dump($_FILES);`

Comment: I don't see any problem with `$_FILES["User.file"]` , are you sure you're accessing the correct key?

Comment: hello there is no html , its mobile application , i didnt use input type='file' its upload file to server but its seem there is no files

Comment: check your html form. Make sure enctype='multipart/form-data'.

Comment: im new in php , i dont know where is the problem and i dont know how to show error

Comment: You should at least learn how to debug input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dots in GET, POST, and COOKIE variables are rewritten to underscores:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["User_file"]["tmp_name"], "/var/www/TEST/".$new_image_name);
```

Comment: +1 it's true! See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651/get-php-to-stop-replacing-characters-in-get-or-post-arrays)