# Get a value from a multidimensional array using the dot syntax

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$conf = array(
'db'    => array(
    'server'    =>  'localhost',
    'user'      =>  'root',
    'pass'      =>  'root',
    'name'      =>  'db',
    ),
'path'  =>  array(
    'site_url'  =>  $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
    'site_dir'  => CMS,
    'admin_url' => conf('path.site_url') . '/admin',
    'admin_dir' => conf('path.site_dir') . DS .'admin',
    'admin_paths' => array(
                'assets' => 'path'
                ),
    ),
);
```

I would like to get a value from this array using a function like so:

```
/**
 * Return or set a configuration setting from the array.
 * @example
 * conf('db.server')    => $conf['db']['server']
 *
 * @param  string $section the section to return the setting from.
 * @param  string $setting the setting name to return.
 * @return mixed           the value of the setting returned.
 */
function conf($path, $value = null) {
    global $conf;
    // We split each word seperated by a dot character
    $paths = explode('.', $path);

    return $conf[$paths[0]][$paths[1]];
}
```

But i would like it if the function resolves all dimensions of the array and not just the first two.

Like this

```
conf('path.admin_paths.assets');
```

would resolve to

```
=> $conf['path']['admin_paths']['assets']
```

How would i do this? Also, how would i make this function if it has another param, would set a value rather than return it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found @Danijel recursive approach a lot cleaner than my initial try. So here's a recursive implementation of the functionality, supporting setting values.

```
function array_get_by_key(&$array, $key, $value = null) {
    list($index, $key) = explode('.', $key, 2);
    if (!isset($array[$index])) throw new Exception("No such key: " . $index);

    if(strlen($key) > 0)
        return array_get_by_key(&$array[$index], $key, $value);

    $old = $array[$index];
    if ($value !== null) $array[$index] = $value;
    return $old;    
}

function config($key, $value = null) {
    global $CONFIG;
    return array_get_by_key(&$CONFIG, $key, $value);
}
```

Test run:

```
$CONFIG = array(
'db'    => array(
    'server'    =>  'localhost',
    'user'      =>  'root',
    'pass'      =>  'root',
    'name'      =>  'db',
    ),
'path'  =>  array(
    'site_url'  =>  'localhost',
    'site_dir'  => 'CMS',
    'admin_url' => 'localhost/admin',
    'admin_dir' => 'localhost/res/admin',
    'admin_paths' => array(
                'assets' => 'path'
                ),
    ),
);

try {
    var_dump(config('db.pass'));
    var_dump(config('path.admin_url', 'localhost/master'));
    var_dump(config('path.admin_url'));
    var_dump(config('path.no_such'));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: trying to access unknown config";
}

// string(4) "root"
// string(15) "localhost/admin"
// string(16) "localhost/master"
// Error: trying to access unknown config
```

Answer (score 6):

This function works:

```
function conf($path, $value = null) {
    global $conf;
    // We split each word seperated by a dot character
    $paths = explode('.', $path);
    $result = $conf;
    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        $result = $result[$path];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**Edit:**

Add Set:

```
function conf($path, $value = null) {
    global $conf;
    // We split each word seperated by a dot character
    $paths = explode('.', $path);
    if ($value === null) {
        // Get
        $result = $conf;
        foreach ($paths as $path) {
            $result = $result[$path];
        }
        return $result;
    }
    // Set
    if (!isset($conf)) $conf = array(); // Initialize array if $conf not set
    $result = &$conf;
    foreach ($paths as $i=>$path) {
        if ($i < count($paths)-1) {
            if (!isset($result[$path])) {
                $result[$path] = array();
            }
            $result = &$result[$path];
        } else {
            $result[$path] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is to get a value. Where is the set?

Answer (score 2):

```
function conf($path,$value=null) {
    global $conf;
    // We split each word seperated by a dot character
    $paths = explode('.', $path);
    $temp = $conf ;
    $ref = &$conf ;
    foreach ( $paths as $p )
    {
        $ref = &$ref[$p] ; // Register the reference to be able to modify $conf var
        if ( isset($temp[$p]) )
            $temp = $temp[$p] ;
        elseif ( $value !== null ) // This key does not exist, and we have a value : time to modify
            $ref = $value ;
        else // Key does not exist and no value to add
            return false ;
    }
    return $temp ;
}
```

Comment: But, how would i use this function to also set values to the global config array. See my edit above.

Comment: I updated with help of swordofpain reference trick, it should do the stuff.

Answer (score 2):

```
function conf($path, $value = null) {
    global $conf;
    $paths = explode('.', $path);

    $array = &$conf; // Reference to the config array

    foreach ($paths as $k) {
        if (!is_array($array)) throw new Exception("No such key: " . $path);
        if (!isset($array[$k])) throw new Exception("No such key: " . $path);

        // In order to walk down the array, we need to first save the ref in
        // $array to $tmp
        $tmp = &$array;
        // Deletes the ref from $array
        unset($array);
        // Create a new ref to the next item
        $array =& $tmp[$k];
        // Delete the save
        unset($tmp);
    }

    $val = $array

    if ($value !== null) $array = $value;

    return $array
}
```

(Code inpired by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539633/parse-string-containing-dots-in-php/22541434#22541434) and Pierre Granger's answer)

Comment: Gives an Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '0'

Comment: throw new Exception("No such key: " . $path); Try a dot instead of the +

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, to get any value from the multidimensional array, recursion is the proper way. Also, you can't use `conf()` function inside the `$conf` array before the array is initialized ( the `global $conf;` will be NULL, eg. not set )

```
function conf( $path ) {
    global $conf;
    return recurse( $conf, explode( '.', $path ) );
}

function recurse( $array, $keys ) {

    if ( isset( $keys[0] ) && isset( $array[$keys[0]] ) ) {

        $array = $array[$keys[0]];
        array_shift( $keys );
        return recurse( $array, $keys );

    } else return is_string( $array ) ? $array : false ;

}


print_r2( conf('path.admin_paths.assets') );    // @str  "path"
print_r2( conf('path.admin_paths') );           // @bool false ( path is invalid )
print_r2( conf('path.admin_url') );             // @str  "/admin" 
print_r2( conf('db.server') );                  // @str  "localhost"
```

Comment: How can i use the conf, function inside the array? I want the array to use other parts of the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented array access class [CompositeKeyArray](https://github.com/Sevavietl/Arrays), that hides away the recursion so you can simply get and set nested keys.

Given that class the original problem can be solved like this:

```
$conf = new CompositeKeyArray($conf);

var_dump($conf[['path', 'admin_paths', 'assets']]); // => string(4) "path"
```

If you want you can change the value:

```
$conf[['path', 'admin_paths', 'assets']] = 'new path';

var_dump($conf[['path', 'admin_paths', 'assets']]); // => string(8) "new path"
```

Or even unset it:

```
unset($conf[['path', 'admin_paths', 'assets']]);

var_dump(isset($conf[['path', 'admin_paths', 'assets']])); // => bool(false)
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dd7b764d1103e453eb47bec4a0e1645b926f0c9e).