# PHP send file only containing the extension

Tags: php, html, download, file-transfer, file-extension

I have some problems with sending files with PHP. I would like to send a file named `.version` *(Note the dot and nothing infort of it)*. The file is sent correctly but my browser renames it to `version`. Therefore the file looses its functionality. The file has to be named like this.

This is the code I use:

```
<?php
  header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
  header("Content-Type: text/version");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\".version\"");
  header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));

  readfile($file);
  exit();
?>
```

`$file` is the correct internal path to the file.
Other headers like the expires header are set in my server config.

If there is information missing I will add if if you ask for it!

Comment: is it going to a windows machine? they dont allow files starting with a dot

Comment: How about `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.version'");` ...

Comment: @Dagon Why not preparing an answer? (It might be a duplicate, however)

Comment: " Why not preparing an answer" not sure what you mean

Comment: @Dagon I can easily create the file by hand on an windows machine. If a simple program can do it why can't my browser? Robert Rozas I will try that!

Comment: @RobertRozas no. That doesn't work. The file will be saved as `.version'`.

Comment: The browser realizes that there shouldn't be a dot in front of it and fixes it, so what's the problem? Users have an option to rename a file before saving anyway.

Comment: Try escaping the dot `filename=\"\.version\"");`

Comment: Didn't work... Sometimes windows is simply annoying me!

Comment: Try `filename=\"&#46;version\"");` or `filename='&#46;version'");` - `&#46;` is the ASCII/HTML equivalent for a dot, as per http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: @Fred-ii- No doesn't work either!

Comment: After a fair amount of research and testing, I'm afraid to say that you're not going to be able to use that type of file (naming) convention. Even when trying to do a simple `href=".version"` wouldn't let me download it under that name. Consult this answer on SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/68742/ (for some added info), where it was pulled from http://php.net/variables.external