# javascript - period changed to underscore

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to make an ajax call which contains the following example parameter

```
farms.company_id=1
```

but when received by PHP it has been changed to

```
farms_company_id=1
```

What's the best way to prevent this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651/get-php-to-stop-replacing-characters-in-get-or-post-arrays

Comment: thank you, perfect answer. Sorry for not spotting the question before posting.