# Points get transformed into underscores php $_GET?

Tags: php, http

So the other day i was debuging some code and the $_GET parameter names were send with dots like for example those:

```
?user.name=test&user.age=20
```

When i wanted to use them i saw they were renamed with underscores like so

```
$_GET['user_name']
$_GET['user_age']
```

So my question is, why is this happening?

Comment: answered in [this SO-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651/get-php-to-stop-replacing-characters-in-get-or-post-arrays)

Comment: thanks for the quick response

Comment: **it is important to note that PHP will automatically replace any dots in incoming variable names with underscores.** from the manual. :)