# How to prevent that $.post converts blanks to underscores?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to send an object to my server that has keys which contains blanks. For some reason that I don't understand the blanks get converted to underscores at the server. How can I prevent this?

```js
var myObject    = {};
myObject['x x'] = 'asdf';

$.post(someUrl, myObject, function (data) {
    ...
}, 'json');
```

In my PHP code $_POST is set to this array:

```php
$_POST = [
    'x_x' => 'asdf'
]
```

Why is that and how do I deal with it? Are there any other characters that get converted this way?

Comment: `var myObject = { 'x x' : 'asdf'}` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get PHP to stop replacing '.' characters in $\_GET or $\_POST arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651/get-php-to-stop-replacing-characters-in-get-or-post-arrays)

Comment: The duplicate is about dots but PHP does also change a bunch of other characters, such as space, because of the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround/solution that works for me is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20365198/57091), which is an answer to the question that Andreas has provided. In short: PHP converts some characters into underscores ([doc comment at php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#81080)). It's not caused by jQuery!

So I wrap my arguments in JS into another object:

```js
var myObject    = {
    arguments: {}
};
myObject.arguments['x x'] = 'asdf';

$.post(someUrl, myObject, function (data) {
    ...
}, 'json');
```

Now I get this structure in PHP that has the unmodified keys:

```php
$_POST = [
    'arguments' => [
        'x x' => 'asdf'
    ]
]
```

And I can access it with `$_POST['arguments']`.