# Youtube PubSubHubBub Integration

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, publish-subscribe, youtube-data-api, websub

Been stuck on this integration problem for hours now. I am trying to subscribe to a youtube channel updates using 
https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe.

[image: Subscription Request]

And my server is setup to respond with:

[image: Server Response]

But when I press **DO IT**, I always get back the error saying *Challenge mismatch.*

I am unsure which parameter I am missing to set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The intended response is not a static value as **hub_challenge**. It should return back the hub.challenge value which is received in query parameters when `GET` request is sent to the callback url.

> More Information

The request will be something like 

`/notifications?hub.topic=https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml%3Fchannel_id%3DUCn0QU5ZOaVnEf7LkdyPF9kQ&hub.challenge=216582865281647747&hub.mode=subscribe&hub.lease_seconds=432000"`

The response of should be the value hub.challenge (216582865281647747)

Comment: If anyone is doing this with PHP, remember that `hub.challenge` has to be accessed as `hub_challenge`

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68742/3899623

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using (either directly or indirectly) https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser, you could do something like this:

`const responseText = request.query['hub.challenge'] || "no challenge"`
`response.send(responseText)`

But even if not that exact syntax, figure out how to log the query parameters that the hub adds when hitting the callback URL. There you will see the value for 'hub.challenge' which you can then send back in the response.