# Filtering on Nested Properties: dot to underscore redirect

Tags: php, symfony, query-string, api-platform.com, symfony-http-foundation

I'm using Symfony and API Platform and I'd like to [filter on nested properties](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#filtering-on-nested-properties).

While this looks very simple, when I go to:

`http://localhost:8000/api/offers?product.color=red`

The request is redirected to:

`http://localhost:8000/api/offers?product_color=red`.

The dot is replaced by an underscore.

I don't fully understand why this happens, but there is a [closed issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9009) about this behavior:

> Closing this one as this is just the way PHP parses HTTP requests and
>   we won't workaround that.

How can I filter on nested properties?

Comment: sounds weird for sure. I mean, the docs in API platform even explicitly support this query string, which was weird, if the redirect always happens. There might be some php ini var for that? Anyway, one ugly workaround **might** be to implement ArrayAccess on the entity and use `product[color]=red` instead. please note, that the closed issue doesn't talk about redirects. it's just replaced in `$_GET`

Comment: Here is a detailed answer for why PHP does this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651/get-php-to-stop-replacing-characters-in-get-or-post-arrays - no workaround / solution though. Seems odd that API Platform doesn't cover this though - their GraphQL integration specifically does: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql/#filtering-on-nested-properties

Comment: @Bananaapple Api Platform and Symfony are PHP frameworks, so it should work around this issue. But somehow, in my case it doesn't seems to do so. I guess there is something in my project that triggers this redirect, but I don't know where.

Comment: Do you actually receive a redirection response, as in a 301? Please share the response headers.

Comment: How exactly are you serving your application? What server are using? Do you have any additional information? It won't be easy to help you if you do not give us a bit more to work with :)

Comment: I'm using Symfony Local Web Server. I don't see any 301 headers. The URL just changes. In the Chrome console I see product.color before loading, then it changes to product_color.

Comment: Please, provide screenshots of your Request headers and Response headers. What you describe is not easy to follow. A request URL location can't just "change" from one URL to another without some sort of redirection.

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example such that others can reproduce your problem

Answer (score 2):

#### Neither PHP nor Symfony (nor API-Platform) will perform a redirect replacing all periods (`.`) to undescore (`_`).

Internally, PHP convert query parameter names containing periods, since these are not valid character for variable names. This is done to maintain compatibility with installations where `register_globals` is on (almost nowhere, nowadays). But this **will not cause a redirect**.

If you are getting redirected, you can check your browser's developer console to see exactly what kind of response header you are getting. E.g.:

> [image]

Note the `Status code: 302` in this case. If you are getting redirected you should receive either a `302` or a `301`.

But if there is any of redirection, it must be happening at the web server level because of some rule you have set.

On a pretty vainilla installation I have running for Api-Plaform I can request a url like this `http://localhost:9097/api/boost_leads?channel.partner=18695` (notice the `channel.partner`) without any issue, and get the response correctly (a `200` status code, no redirection):

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add libraries:

```
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\OrderFilter;
```

Then to add the annotation

```
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"exams": "exact"})
```

After this is the route en ApiPlatform

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/questions?exams=1
```