# The symbol of dot has been replaced in parameter names on the underscore (PHP)

Tags: php, post, parameters, underscore.js, dot

I send POST param with name "param.name"

If I read the php://input everything ok, but if I try to get param from an array $_POST['param.name'] that it is absent because the dot was replaced to underscore and I need to get param this way $_POST['param_name'].

Maybe some settings in PHP I should tune...

I use PHP 7.4.15

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get PHP to stop replacing '.' characters in $\_GET or $\_POST arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651/get-php-to-stop-replacing-characters-in-get-or-post-arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected PHP behavior as mentioned in [their official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#language.variables.external.dot-in-names). As far as I know, PHP applies this rule when parsing the `$_POST` superglobal because of reasons related to backwards compatibility (`register_globals`).

The reason for `php://input` showing your actual parameter name is because this is a raw input stream, showing data that has not yet been parsed by PHP. While `$_POST` data **is** parsed.

In short, avoid using dot notation for PHP input parameter naming or be willing to implement your own parsing mechanism in order to support it.