# GET parameters that include dots cannot be checked in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm trying to determine whether a parameter is in the URL or not. I use:

```
$request->has('key');
```

And it's been working properly until now when I have to check wethere I have openid.ns parameter in the URL. If I remove the .(dot) everything works as expected, but:

**URL:** myhost.dev/auth/login?filter[openid.ns]=http://google.bg/

And then

```
dd($request->has('filter.openid.ns');
```

returns `false`.

What causes this odd behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68742/7451109

Comment: try to `request()->route()->parameters()` and check it's result. It will show you how to access it